# Prison Architect crashes xServer

Tags: technical-issues, linux, prison-architect

When I begin playing Prison Architect, I create a new world and after 10-15 seconds the XServer dies and restarts leaving me at the linuxmint login screen and I really have a quite beefy computer that runs PA fine on Windows.

Platform: LinuxMint 64bit Gnone + Steam

Comment: Report the problem to the developer the game is in an alpha state this is to be expected.

Comment: What errors does the xserver report when crashing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the game has gone through several updates to resolve server crashes, and this question no longer seems relevant.